# Apache NiFi: XML to Hive conversion

Tags: xml, hive, apache-nifi

I am trying to convert XML file to Hive Table via Apache NiFi. Schema of XML will be available at runtime . I have tried creating a pipeline this way:

```
GetFile -> TransformXML -> InferAvroSchem -> Yet to design (create a Hive Table and dump the data into it)
```

With the above apparoach I need to provide xslt and attributes which will be available only after XML is processed.

Need further guidance on achieving XML to Hive when schema of XML is known at runtime

Comment: Can you use a Hive XML serde and skip any conversion?

Comment: @James will Hive XML Serde infer column metadata automatically?
Also by this suggestion do you mean a single node for PutHiveQL right?

Comment: No, I don't think it will infer a schema from your XML automatically, but it would let you impose a schema without converting XML to something else.

Comment: @James I am trying to create a Tool out of it hence providing schema is not an option  that I know at design time.